# "Incompatible Office products are installed on your machine" when opening Office documents or browsing OneDrive or SharePoint Site

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-office-2013

I'm running Office 2013 Pro Plus 32-bit (MSI-based) on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. When trying to open an Excel, Word, or PowerPoint documents I get this error message:

> Sorry, we can't perform this action. Incompatible Office products are installed on your machine. If you have an administrator, please contact them for help.

After clicking **OK** the file opens and functions normally.

Further, if I attempt to browse OneDrive or a SharePoint site through Word or Excel the same error is displayed. After clicking OK I can continue browsing the connected service.  Unfortunately, removing the services doesn't solve the problem.

How can I fix this?

---

#### Additional Details

- The error is only displayed when opening the first document in the Office program. Once the error has been displayed, I can open other documents and don't get the error.
- I only get the error when opening documents stored on a mapped network drive.  No error is displayed when opening documents stored on my local hard drive.

In the `Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft Office Alerts` log I found an entry with event ID 300 and Source "Microsoft Office 15 Alerts" that has this text:

> Microsoft Excel
>   Sorry, we can’t perform this action. Incompatible Office products are installed on your machine. If you have an administrator, please contact them for help.
>   P1: 702089
>   P2: 15.0.4693.1000
>   P3:
>   P4:

**My research/Attempted Solutions:**

- I tried deleting my [Personal Macro workbook](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566?CorrelationId=e8a61f9b-ad34-4f87-8cb4-c5bd6083297a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). No change.
- I found this [Microsoft forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d3d869ee-2477-481f-8cd1-a3a09f10c733/feb-2015-update-onedrive-for-business-error-incompatible-office-products-are-installed-on-your) which suggests uninstalling SharePoint Designer 2010, but I don't have that product installed.
- The forum refers to [KB2920798](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2920798), which I installed today, but I'm able to open my Office files, contrary to the KB's claim that `This update provides you an informative message when you cannot open an Office document`.  I do not have any click-to-run Office products installed.
- Over the weekend I installed SimCity 3000 Unlimited which is an older game.  It installed "MS Access 97 SP2 Runtime.  **Update:** Uninstalling this didn't help.
- I also installed available Windows Updates this weekend, about 20-30 of them to my recollection.

Comment: Gotta love MS. "Incompatible Office products are installed on your machine..." Does it tell you what these offending products are? Nope. Of course not. Why would you need to know *that*. Still, marginally better than "An unknown error has occurred" which I get from time to time.

Comment: You have both 32- and 64-bit Office components and/or applications installed. This is an unsupported scenario. Also, don’t ever use 64-bit Office unless you’re looking for trouble.

Comment: I just deleted my answer as it's clearly wrong (no point polluting the forum). @DanielB is on the money I reckon.

Comment: @DanielB I do? What makes you think I have any 64-bit Office products installed?

Comment: @Twisty - I would bet money that you do.  Because Office 2013 was the first major release of Office that actively promoted it.  Unless you have a volume license for office you likely do have a Click-to-Run office product installed since that was the only consumer version most people have.  You should try getting rid of that Access 97 runtime installation.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll take the bet! ;) All of my Office products are Volume License and they're all the 32-bit versions. I was simply wondering if DanielB saw something in my post suggesting I might be wrong about that last point.

Comment: @Ramhound I uninstalled the Access 97 runtime but the problem persists. I've discovered the problem only occurs if the file is on a mapped network drive.

Comment: It looks like there's a new cause for this problem that might be related to a Windows 10 update. If I fix it I'll update my answer.

Comment: Just to point out, uninstalling SimCity 3000 from my system removed the Comic Sans fonts, and it tried to remove Arial as well.

Comment: I recently signed up for Office 365 E5 and was logged in from Word briefly. The only recently installed new office component on my machine is the MS Office Access 2007 database engine. And yet, this error started to occur when I want to save to a Sharepoint drive that is mapped via Webdav. Uninstalling the Access 2007 component did not resolve it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**You need to uninstall the stand-alone Microsoft OneDrive <del>for Business</del> 2013 sync client**.  *[Edit: As noted in the comments, this issue is caused by any version of the stand-alone sync client, not just the Business version.]* It looks like this in Add/Remove Programs:
[image]

The [stand-alone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903984)  sync client is the `Incompatible Office product installed on your machine` referred to by the [February 10, 2015 update for Office 2013 (KB2920798)](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/2920798) update.  Your edition of Office 2013 came with its own OneDrive for Business 2013 sync client:

> If you have one of the following versions of Office 2013, you already have the OneDrive for Business (formerly SkyDrive Pro) sync client installed:
>
> - Office Professional Plus 2013
> - Office 365 Enterprise E3
> - Office 365 Midsize Business
> - Office 365 Small Business Premium

This included OneDrive sync client is conflicting with the stand-alone client.  As noted in the [installation instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903984), the stand-alone version is only meant to be installed with Office 2010:

> The OneDrive for Business client can be installed side by side with Office 2010....Using OneDrive for Business alongside the 2007 Office system is not a supported scenario.

Comment: I had this error but I didn't have the OneDrive for Business client installed.  I did have the regular OneDrive client installed, which shows up in the uninstall list simply as "Microsoft OneDrive" with the blue cloud logo.  Uninstalling that fixed the issue.  (I'm not sure how it got installed as I'm on Windows 8.1, which supports OneDrive without the client.  The issue started after Patch Tuesday patches were installed for May 2015.)

Comment: Interesting.  If others corroborate this observation I might edit my answer to suggest *any* additional OneDrive client may be the culprit, not just the Business version.

Comment: Like Aaron, I also only had the regular OneDrive client (with the blue cloud icon) installed, and not the OneDrive for Business client. I uninstalled OneDrive, and am hoping that the error disappears.

Comment: In my case, removing OneDrive for Business from Office 2013 Professional package solved the issue. Probably outdated version or something else that caused the problem, but was related to OneDrive for Business.

Comment: As an additional data-point, I also had only the "Microsoft OneDrive" product installed. I had to reboot after uninstalling it, but after that the message has disappeared.

Comment: OK, so I did an "Online Repair" of my click-to-run installed version of Office, and found it was not happy about coexisting with Windows Installer based Office Programs I had: MS Visio + MS Project. It said "Click to run and Windows Installer editions of Office programs don't get along for this version". Time to whip out the old ISO.

Comment: I too got this error message and resolved it the same way @Aaron did. The issue only popped up today, but the OneDrive client was installed on May 25th and I'm sure I've used office documents straight from OneDrive in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

**You may also need to uninstall the stand alone version of OneNote 2013.**

Recently OneNote 2013 was made free, on a new Development Machine I had installed OneNote, however a few months later I realized that I needed the rest of the Office Suite on this machine. Installing from Media I opted not to install OneNote (because it was already installed of course!).

This appears to be an unsupported configuration.

To resolve it uninstall the stand alone OneNote 2013 install and then reinstall OneNote from the Office Suite in Programs and Features (in my case Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013).

Answer (score 2):

My user had this issue because they had both Office 2013 ProPlus and Office 365 installed.  We fixed it by uninstalling both Office 2013 and 365 and reinstalling Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by having both click-to-run (e.g., Office 365 downloaded) and MSI (regular installer) installed Office applications on a computer at the same time. For example, if you install Visio from a volume license ISO download and then install Office 2013 Pro Plus using an Office 365 E3 license by downloading it from the portal, you can get this error.

Here are some solutions for this case (only the first has no additional cost):

- Uninstall the click-to-run software (e.g., Office 365 Pro Plus) and download the *retail trial* (i.e., MSI installer) of the same software (e.g., Office 2013 Pro Plus Trial). Install the trial and activate it by going to File -> Account and choosing the option to activate with a subscription. Log on with an Office 365 license with an E3 account. Note that you **cannot** use a volume license ISO for this solution.
- Purchase an Office 365 license for the MSI installed software, uninstall the MSI installation, assign the subscription license to the appropriate user and download the click-to-run installer from the portal.
- The opposite of the last solution, uninstall the click-to-run software and purchase a volume or retail license for that software and install the MSI package from the DVD, ISO, or download.

Answer (score 0):

**Having OneNote open causes this**

In reference to my comment to the original question, it turns out that in my case this was simply caused by OneNote running. Once I closed the OneNote window, I was able to save an Excel spreadsheet to the Sharepoint drive.

I have Windows 10 and Office Professional Plus 2013, Visio Professional 2013, all MSI installs.